# python 'listen' creates established socket. why?

Tags: python, tcp, tcpserver, listen, backlog

I created simple server.py that `listen` connection, but not `accept` connection.

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = 1234
server_socket.bind(("", PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)

while 1:
        pass

server_socket.close()
```

When I run this code,

- `nc` client could connect to the server
- server created `ESTABLISHED` socket for the client

  ```
  netstat -an | grep 1234
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1234            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 3.3.3.3:1234      4.4.4.4:51493     ESTABLISHED
  tcp        0      0 3.3.3.3:1234      4.4.4.4:51494     ESTABLISHED
  ```

**Question:**
As far as I know, `listen` just gather connection in backlog queue, and then `accept` creates ESTABLISHED socket.
However the result: `listen` itself creates socket.

I also checked [source code](https://github.com/biosbits/bits/blob/master/python/_socket.py#L483) but could not find the socket creation code.
Can anyone knows the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, listen just gather connection in backlog queue, and then accept creates ESTABLISHED socket.

This is wrong. `listen` tells the OS to accept new connections.  `accept` then gets the inside the OS already established connections into the application. The backlog parameter for `listen` defines roughly how many connections can be accepted by the OS before they application needs to retrieve these using `accept`.

Therefore, the OS will accept new connections as long as `listen` was called, even before `accept` is called.